# typedef structure with * to the name in c

Tags: c, pointers, structure, typedef

I've come across this strange way to define a structure in C and I cannot find anywhere what this really is?

```
    typedef struct {
        int val;
    } *Name;
```

What is the difference to this?

```
typedef struct {
   int val;
} Name;
```

I see however that I have to use "->" on the first and "." on the second, but what is really the difference?

Comment: @usr, That's not the same topic man.

Comment: Thats not my question?

Comment: First `Name` is a type that is a pointer a struct.  Avoid hiding a pointer in a type - only good in select circumstances

Comment: @chux thanks for the advice even tho it was not part of the question.

Comment: @lurr "what is really the difference?" opens the issue up.  A real difference is that the first is only good coding in select cases.  The 2nd is good coding.  [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first case

```
typedef struct {
    int val;
} *Name;
```

the name `Name` is declared as an alias for the type pointer to an unnamed structure.

You can use this pointer type for example the following way

```
Name ptr = malloc( sizeof( *ptr ) );
```

and then you can write for example

```
ptr->val = 10;
```

or

```
( *ptr ).val = 10;
```

That is in this declaration there is declared the pointer `ptr` of the type Name and dynamically created an object of the structure and the pointer points to this dynamically created object.

In the second case

```
typedef struct {
    int val;
} Name;
```

the name `Name` is declared as an alias for the unnamed structure itself.

To declare an object of this type you can just write

```
Name name;
```

and then

```
name.val = 10;
```

or just

```
Name name = { 10 };
```

and an object of the structure type will be created.

Or if you want to allocate an object of the structure type dynamically you can write

```
Name *ptr = malloc( sizeof( Name ) );
```

To make it more clear here are another examples of using typedef.

```
typedef int A[10];
```

this typedef declares the name `A` as an alias for the array type `int[10]`.

you can write after that

```
A a;
```

This declaration declares array object `a` of the type `A` that is equivalent to `int[10]`.

This declaration

```
typedef int ( *A )[10];
```

declares the name `A` as an alias to the type pointer to an array of type `int[10]`.

This declaration can be used for example the following way

```
int a[10];
A ptr_a = &a;
```

Comment: When using "*" i have to use malloc to instantiate it, but without that I can simply say Name name; name.val = 3? Why is that? thanks man

Comment: Thanks, another question if u dont mind, the argument to sizeof is *ptr, does it matter or is it preferable over giving sizeof *Name?

Comment: @Lurr Name is a type. You may not write *Name. The unary operator * is applied to objects.

Answer (score 4):

When you write

```
typedef struct {
   int val;
} Name;
```

you're saying "the name `Name` now refers to a `struct` with one element, an `int` named `val`."

When you write

```
typedef struct {
   int val;
} *Name;
```

the star changes the meaning so that this says "the name `Name` now refers to a *pointer* to a `struct` with one member, an `int` named `val`." This is why you need to use the arrow operator rather than a dot: in the first case, `Name` is a type that's an honest-to-goodness structure, and in the second `Name` is a type that's a pointer to a structure.